# Is it possible to directly connect Arduino Mini to PC?

Tags: usb, arduino

I have an Arduino Pro Mini and a USB cable with just wires from one side. Is it possible to connect these wires directly with Arduino? I mean, +Data to Rx, -Data to Tx, +5v to one of the numbered pins and ground to GND.

Comment: Yes, will have an answer shortly, just editing my pictures for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, in fact you could damage your Arduino doing this.

The RX and TX pins are for Serial (which run at higher voltages than 5volts)

Your best option would be to buy a USB to Serial convetor and then use a MAX232 chip (it is a chip that converts TTL logic (5volts) to RS232 (3 to -25 volts).

Or you could try using the v-usb library. Google v-usb online.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not as you think, there is a raw voltage and regulated voltage but why run the risk of wiring incorrectly.

The best is use USB device between FTDI.

Here is a simple pin connection to make programming easier in photos.  (quality of photos may not be best but you get the idea from them) I don't show how I add the blue to the pins but that is shrink tubing heated.

[image: Arduino with pins attached]  This makes easier programming of your Arduino this can be attached to a programmer quickly and effectively.

[image: USB attachment from sparkfun]
You can get this from Sparkfun for very cheap [FTDI](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716)

[image: Pins to add to the arduino]

[image: Mated pair ready for interface to any USB computer compatible]